# Does the warping of spacetime by mass alter homogeneity of space?

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws

It is said that the conservation laws are a result of homogeneity and isotropy of space and time. But does the warping of spacetime by mass as predicted by GTR alter that? If not, how can a curved spacetime be isotropic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the small clumps of matter in the universe breaks the homogeneity of the universe. In general relativity this is connected to how mass-energy is a source of the gravity field that breaks conformal symmetry of gravity. Conformal gravity is governed by the Weyl tensor, which is vacuum solution. Matter describes the Ricci curvature that breaks conformal symmetry. This is connected to the fact that the little bits of stuff here and there, things like galaxies etc, do break some symmetries of spacetime. This includes homogeneity and isotropy.